# Exit from express, nodejs programme on button click

Tags: node.js, express, eventemitter

I have created a file import functionality using nodejs,express and socket.io. Everything is working fine but now I have to implement a feature in which , user clicks on a button and on click of this button, I want to cancel/stop the execution of code (wherever the control is at that moment, should not execute further). I have tried return, res.end(), res.send(), eventEmitter, throw error etc but script processing is not getting stopped. On using process.exit, code execution stops but it shutdown for all users no matter from where they are operating(i.e if 5 users are using import feature, code executions stops for all five users). Can anybody have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an interval checking the if the state of the button (button click should change a flag) once you check the flag you can resolve your function ( the function should be a promise) and then it will stop the execution of the code example:

```js
let flag = false

function test(){
  return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
    let interval = setInterval(()=>{
        if (flag){
          
            res();
          }
    },1000)

    /*rest of code goes here*/
  })
}
```